# How to make use of Progress DataDirect ODBC for Microsoft SQL Server to access sql server database in Progress 10.2B?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, openedge

I am trying access SQL Server2012 database from **Progress OpenEdge (v10.2B)** application using *Progress DataDirect odbc for Microsoft SQL server*. The sample ABL program provided [here](https://github.com/PeterJudge-PSC/abl_odbc_api) gives the error because Progress 10.2B doesn't seem to support **Progress.Json.***  class. Can anybody suggest me the solution for this? Any sample ABL program that runs on version 10.2B would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: From the README: "This project assumes you are using OpenEdge 11.4.0+. For a version of this sample that works with 11.3 and earlier, please use the code and instructions from Integrating DataDirect Cloud and Progress Easyl into OpenEdge using the ODBC Bridge Sample Applications on Progress Communities."

Comment: @TomBascom the sample provided for 11.3 and earlier also doesn't work for 10.2B. Thay may work for 11.x only. Same issue with this sample as well. Could not find class or interface: Progress.Json.*

Answer (score 0):

This presentation (and the samples associated with it) talks about using .NET to do various things in the 4GL and the code should work with OpenEdge 10.2B.  Slide 20 refers to a sample program for getting SQL data that should be in the zip file.

http://pugchallenge.org/downloads2016/568%20-%20PugChallenge2016.pptx

http://pugchallenge.org/downloads2016/568%20-%20DotNet.zip

Comment: Thank you for considering it but the program gives the errors like <i>Invalid datatype specified: SqlConnection. Specify a datatype such as 'character' or the name of a class. (5638)
**  Could not understand line 17. (196) </i> for every object defined. And I also didn't see the data source name (or odbc driver) specified in the program, don't we need to access sql server db on remote host.